# how to fix "ERROR MongoRDD: WARNING: Partitioning failed. Partitioning using the 'DefaultMongoPartitioner$' failed." in pyspark

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

When I run the code locally it runs fine but when I run in the server the same code I get the above error. 
When I run locally I read the data from local mongodb then I have no error. But when I run in server I read data from mongodb replica server

I have tried changing the

```
".config("spark.mongodb.input.partitionerOptions", "MongoPaginateByCountPartitioner")"
```

to

```
MongoDefaultPartitioner,MongoSplitVectorPartitioner
```

```
def save_n_rename(df):
   print('------------------------------------- WRITING INITIATED -------------------------------------------')
   df.write.format('com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource').mode('overwrite')\
       .option('uri', '{}/{}.Revenue_Analytics'.format(mongo_final_url, mongo_final_db)).save()
   print('------------------------------------- WRITING COMPLETED -------------------------------------------')
```

```
def main():

    spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .master(props.get(env, 'executionMode')) \
        .appName("Revenue_Analytics") \
        .config("spark.mongodb.input.partitionerOptions", "MongoPaginateByCountPartitioner") \
        .getOrCreate()
    start = time()
    df = processing(spark)
    mins_elapsed, secs_elapsed = divmod(time() - start, 60)
    print("----------- Completed processing in {}m {:.2f}s -----------".format(mins_elapsed, secs_elapsed))
    save_n_rename(df)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

EDIT 1:
MongoDB Version: 4.2.0
Pyspark version: 2.4.4

traceback:

```
19/10/24 12:57:45 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 7.006073 ms
19/10/24 12:57:45 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 4.714324 ms
19/10/24 12:57:45 INFO cluster: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[172.16.10.252:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
19/10/24 12:57:45 INFO cluster: Cluster description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
19/10/24 12:57:45 INFO connection: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:45, serverValue:172200}] to 172.16.10.252:27017
19/10/24 12:57:45 INFO cluster: Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=172.16.10.252:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 0, 0]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=7, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=419102, setName='rs0', canonicalAddress=mongo-repl-3:27017, hosts=[172.16.10.250:27017, mongo-repl-2:27017, mongo-repl-3:27017], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='172.16.10.250:27017', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=null, setVersion=3, lastWriteDate=Thu Oct 24 12:57:45 IST 2019, lastUpdateTimeNanos=2312527044492704}
19/10/24 12:57:45 INFO MongoClientCache: Creating MongoClient: [172.16.10.252:27017]
19/10/24 12:57:45 INFO connection: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:46, serverValue:172201}] to 172.16.10.252:27017
19/10/24 12:57:45 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 6.280343 ms
19/10/24 12:57:45 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 3.269567 ms
19/10/24 12:57:45 INFO cluster: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[172.16.10.252:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
19/10/24 12:57:45 INFO cluster: Cluster description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
19/10/24 12:57:45 INFO connection: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:47, serverValue:172202}] to 172.16.10.252:27017
19/10/24 12:57:45 INFO cluster: Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=172.16.10.252:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 0, 0]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=7, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=570933, setName='rs0', canonicalAddress=mongo-repl-3:27017, hosts=[172.16.10.250:27017, mongo-repl-2:27017, mongo-repl-3:27017], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='172.16.10.250:27017', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=null, setVersion=3, lastWriteDate=Thu Oct 24 12:57:45 IST 2019, lastUpdateTimeNanos=2312527212534350}
19/10/24 12:57:45 INFO MongoClientCache: Creating MongoClient: [172.16.10.252:27017]
19/10/24 12:57:45 INFO connection: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:48, serverValue:172203}] to 172.16.10.252:27017
19/10/24 12:57:45 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 6.001824 ms
19/10/24 12:57:45 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 3.610373 ms
19/10/24 12:57:45 INFO cluster: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[172.16.10.252:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
19/10/24 12:57:45 INFO cluster: Cluster description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
19/10/24 12:57:45 INFO connection: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:49, serverValue:172204}] to 172.16.10.252:27017
19/10/24 12:57:45 INFO cluster: Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=172.16.10.252:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 0, 0]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=7, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=502689, setName='rs0', canonicalAddress=mongo-repl-3:27017, hosts=[172.16.10.250:27017, mongo-repl-2:27017, mongo-repl-3:27017], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='172.16.10.250:27017', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=null, setVersion=3, lastWriteDate=Thu Oct 24 12:57:45 IST 2019, lastUpdateTimeNanos=2312527352871977}
19/10/24 12:57:45 INFO MongoClientCache: Creating MongoClient: [172.16.10.252:27017]
19/10/24 12:57:45 INFO connection: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:50, serverValue:172205}] to 172.16.10.252:27017
19/10/24 12:57:46 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 5.552305 ms
19/10/24 12:57:46 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 3.230598 ms
19/10/24 12:57:46 INFO cluster: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[172.16.10.252:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
19/10/24 12:57:46 INFO cluster: Cluster description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
19/10/24 12:57:46 INFO connection: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:51, serverValue:172206}] to 172.16.10.252:27017
19/10/24 12:57:46 INFO cluster: Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=172.16.10.252:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 0, 0]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=7, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=535708, setName='rs0', canonicalAddress=mongo-repl-3:27017, hosts=[172.16.10.250:27017, mongo-repl-2:27017, mongo-repl-3:27017], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='172.16.10.250:27017', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=null, setVersion=3, lastWriteDate=Thu Oct 24 12:57:46 IST 2019, lastUpdateTimeNanos=2312527492689014}
19/10/24 12:57:46 INFO MongoClientCache: Creating MongoClient: [172.16.10.252:27017]
19/10/24 12:57:46 INFO connection: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:52, serverValue:172207}] to 172.16.10.252:27017
19/10/24 12:57:46 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 14.755534 ms
19/10/24 12:57:46 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 5.132629 ms
19/10/24 12:57:46 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 5.480881 ms
19/10/24 12:57:46 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 4.944708 ms
19/10/24 12:57:46 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 5.26496 ms
19/10/24 12:57:46 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 5.270467 ms
19/10/24 12:57:46 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 5.068084 ms
19/10/24 12:57:46 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 4.947876 ms
19/10/24 12:57:46 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 4.996435 ms
19/10/24 12:57:46 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 5.080908 ms
19/10/24 12:57:46 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 4.843392 ms
19/10/24 12:57:46 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 4.93398 ms
19/10/24 12:57:46 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 6.395543 ms
19/10/24 12:57:46 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 5.189256 ms
19/10/24 12:57:46 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 6.958948 ms
19/10/24 12:57:46 INFO MongoClientCache: Closing MongoClient: [172.16.10.252:27017]
19/10/24 12:57:46 INFO connection: Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:32, serverValue:172187}] to 172.16.10.252:27017 because the pool has been closed.
19/10/24 12:57:46 INFO MongoClientCache: Closing MongoClient: [172.16.10.252:27017]
19/10/24 12:57:46 INFO connection: Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:30, serverValue:172185}] to 172.16.10.252:27017 because the pool has been closed.
19/10/24 12:57:49 INFO MongoClientCache: Closing MongoClient: [172.16.10.252:27017]
19/10/24 12:57:49 INFO connection: Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:36, serverValue:172191}] to 172.16.10.252:27017 because the pool has been closed.
19/10/24 12:57:49 INFO MongoClientCache: Closing MongoClient: [172.16.10.252:27017]
19/10/24 12:57:49 INFO connection: Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:38, serverValue:172193}] to 172.16.10.252:27017 because the pool has been closed.
19/10/24 12:57:49 INFO MongoClientCache: Closing MongoClient: [172.16.10.252:27017]
19/10/24 12:57:49 INFO connection: Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:40, serverValue:172195}] to 172.16.10.252:27017 because the pool has been closed.
19/10/24 12:57:50 INFO MongoClientCache: Closing MongoClient: [172.16.10.252:27017]
19/10/24 12:57:50 INFO connection: Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:42, serverValue:172197}] to 172.16.10.252:27017 because the pool has been closed.
19/10/24 12:57:50 INFO MongoClientCache: Closing MongoClient: [172.16.10.252:27017]
19/10/24 12:57:50 INFO connection: Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:44, serverValue:172199}] to 172.16.10.252:27017 because the pool has been closed.
19/10/24 12:57:50 INFO MongoClientCache: Closing MongoClient: [172.16.10.252:27017]
19/10/24 12:57:50 INFO connection: Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:46, serverValue:172201}] to 172.16.10.252:27017 because the pool has been closed.
19/10/24 12:57:50 INFO MongoClientCache: Closing MongoClient: [172.16.10.252:27017]
19/10/24 12:57:50 INFO connection: Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:48, serverValue:172203}] to 172.16.10.252:27017 because the pool has been closed.
19/10/24 12:57:51 INFO MongoClientCache: Closing MongoClient: [172.16.10.252:27017]
19/10/24 12:57:51 INFO connection: Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:50, serverValue:172205}] to 172.16.10.252:27017 because the pool has been closed.
19/10/24 12:57:51 INFO MongoClientCache: Closing MongoClient: [172.16.10.252:27017]
19/10/24 12:57:51 INFO connection: Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:52, serverValue:172207}] to 172.16.10.252:27017 because the pool has been closed.
19/10/24 12:58:03 ERROR MongoRDD: 
-----------------------------
WARNING: Partitioning failed.
-----------------------------

Partitioning using the 'DefaultMongoPartitioner$' failed.

Please check the stacktrace to determine the cause of the failure or check the Partitioner API documentation.
Note: Not all partitioners are suitable for all toplogies and not all partitioners support views.%n

-----------------------------

19/10/24 12:58:04 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
19/10/24 12:58:04 INFO MongoClientCache: Closing MongoClient: [172.16.10.252:27017]
19/10/24 12:58:04 INFO connection: Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:34, serverValue:172189}] to 172.16.10.252:27017 because the pool has been closed.
19/10/24 12:58:04 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://172.16.10.242:4040
19/10/24 12:58:04 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
19/10/24 12:58:04 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
19/10/24 12:58:04 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
19/10/24 12:58:04 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
19/10/24 12:58:04 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
19/10/24 12:58:04 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
19/10/24 12:58:04 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
19/10/24 12:58:04 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-04e7bf58-133a-4c10-b5c4-20ac740ab880
19/10/24 12:58:04 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-e36f3499-1c23-4f25-b5ce-3a6a9685f9bb
19/10/24 12:58:04 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-e36f3499-1c23-4f25-b5ce-3a6a9685f9bb/pyspark-28bc9fe4-4bd8-44dd-b541-a25def4e3930

------------------------------------- WRITING INITIATED -------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/svr_data_analytic/hmis-analytics-data-processing/src/main/python/sales/revenue.py", line 402, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/svr_data_analytic/hmis-analytics-data-processing/src/main/python/sales/revenue.py", line 398, in main
    save_n_rename(df)
  File "/home/svr_data_analytic/hmis-analytics-data-processing/src/main/python/sales/revenue.py", line 383, in save_n_rename
    .option('uri', '{}/{}.Revenue_Analytics'.format(mongo_final_url, mongo_final_db)).save()
  File "/home/svr_data_analytic/spark/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 736, in save
  File "/home/svr_data_analytic/spark/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/home/svr_data_analytic/spark/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/home/svr_data_analytic/spark/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o740.save.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
Exchange hashpartitioning(itemtype_id#4652, 200)
+- *(70) Project [quantity#3658, amount#3578, discount#3591, item_net_amount#3761, billitems_id#3816, bill_doctor_id#3879, item_doctor_id#3902, bill_no#5673, name#5803, bill_date#5671, type#5851, total_amount#6053, bill_discount#6054, bills_id#6120, Patient_Type#6307, bill_type#4350, admit_doc_id#1096, item_name#4400, itemtype_id#4652, group_name#5625, category_name#5511, classification_name#5397]
   +- SortMergeJoin [item_classification_id#4961], [item_cls_id#5404], LeftOuter
      :- *(67) Sort [item_classification_id#4961 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(item_classification_id#4961, 200)
      :     +- *(66) Project [quantity#3658, amount#3578, discount#3591, item_net_amount#3761, billitems_id#3816, bill_doctor_id#3879, item_doctor_id#3902, bill_no#5673, name#5803, bill_date#5671, type#5851, total_amount#6053, bill_discount#6054, bills_id#6120, Patient_Type#6307, bill_type#4350, admit_doc_id#1096, item_name#4400, itemtype_id#4652, item_classification_id#4961, group_name#5625, category_name#5511]
      :        +- SortMergeJoin [item_category_id#4857], [item_cat_id#5510], LeftOuter
      :           :- *(63) Sort [item_category_id#4857 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      :           :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(item_category_id#4857, 200)
      :           :     +- *(62) Project [quantity#3658, amount#3578, discount#3591, item_net_amount#3761, billitems_id#3816, bill_doctor_id#3879, item_doctor_id#3902, bill_no#5673, name#5803, bill_date#5671, type#5851, total_amount#6053, bill_discount#6054, bills_id#6120, Patient_Type#6307, bill_type#4350, admit_doc_id#1096, item_name#4400, itemtype_id#4652, item_category_id#4857, item_classification_id#4961, group_name#5625]
      :           :        +- SortMergeJoin [item_group_id#4754], [item_grp_id#5624], LeftOuter
      :           :           :- *(59) Sort [item_group_id#4754 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      :           :           :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(item_group_id#4754, 200)
      :           :           :     +- *(58) Project [quantity#3658, amount#3578, discount#3591, item_net_amount#3761, billitems_id#3816, bill_doctor_id#3879, item_doctor_id#3902, bill_no#5673, name#5803, bill_date#5671, type#5851, total_amount#6053, bill_discount#6054, bills_id#6120, Patient_Type#6307, bill_type#4350, admit_doc_id#1096, item_name#4400, itemtype_id#4652, item_group_id#4754, item_category_id#4857, item_classification_id#4961]
      :           :           :        +- SortMergeJoin [billitems_item_id#3857], [item_id#4551], LeftOuter
      :           :           :           :- *(55) Sort [billitems_item_id#3857 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      :           :           :           :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(billitems_item_id#3857, 200)
      :           :           :           :     +- *(54) Project [quantity#3658, amount#3578, discount#3591, item_net_amount#3761, billitems_id#3816, billitems_item_id#3857, bill_doctor_id#3879, item_doctor_id#3902, bill_no#5673, name#5803, bill_date#5671, type#5851, total_amount#6053, bill_discount#6054, bills_id#6120, Patient_Type#6307, bill_type#4350, admit_doc_id#1096]
      :           :           :           :        +- SortMergeJoin [ip_app_id#6144], [ipapp_id#1094], LeftOuter
      :           :           :           :           :- *(51) Sort [ip_app_id#6144 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      :           :           :           :           :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(ip_app_id#6144, 200)
      :           :           :           :           :     +- *(50) Project [quantity#3658, amount#3578, discount#3591, item_net_amount#3761, billitems_id#3816, billitems_item_id#3857, bill_doctor_id#3879, item_doctor_id#3902, bill_no#5673, name#5803, bill_date#5671, type#5851, total_amount#6053, bill_discount#6054, bills_id#6120, ip_app_id#6144, Patient_Type#6307, bill_type#4350]
      :           :           :           :           :        +- *(50) SortMergeJoin [bill_id#3836], [bills_id#6120], Inner
      :           :           :           :           :           :- *(39) Sort [bill_id#3836 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      :           :           :           :           :           :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(bill_id#3836, 200)
      :           :           :           :           :           :     +- *(38) Project [quantity#3658, amount#3578, discount#3591, total#3666 AS item_net_amount#3761, _id#3577.oid AS billitems_id#3816, bills#3586.$id.oid AS bill_id#3836, item#3620.$id.oid AS billitems_item_id#3857, bill_doctor#3582.$id.oid AS bill_doctor_id#3879, doctor#3594.$id.oid AS item_doctor_id#3902]
      :           :           :           :           :           :        +- *(38) Filter ((((cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(bill_date#3581, yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss, Some(Asia/Kolkata)), yyyy, Some(Asia/Kolkata)) as int) >= 2018) && isnotnull(bills#3586.$id.oid)) && isnotnull(is_previous_bill_item#3616)) && (is_previous_bill_item#3616 = false))
      :           :           :           :           :           :           +- *(38) Scan MongoRelation(MongoRDD[25] at RDD at MongoRDD.scala:51,Some(StructType(StructField(_id,StructType(StructField(oid,StringType,true)),true), StructField(amount,DoubleType,true), StructField(billDoctor,StructType(StructField($ref,StringType,true), StructField($id,StructType(StructField(oid,StringType,true)),true)),true), StructField(billType,StructType(StructField($db,StringType,true), StructField($id,StructType(StructField(oid,StringType,true)),true), StructField($ref,StringType,true)),true), StructField(bill_date,TimestampType,true), StructField(bill_doctor,StructType(StructField($ref,StringType,true), StructField($id,StructType(StructField(oid,StringType,true)),true), StructField($db,StringType,true)),true), StructField(bill_doctor_name,StringType,true), StructField(bill_item_unique_id,StringType,true), StructField(bill_unique_id,StringType,true), StructField(bills,StructType(StructField($db,StringType,true), StructField($id,StructType(StructField(oid,StringType,true)),true), StructField($ref,StringType,true)),true), StructField(cgst_amount,DoubleType,true), StructField(cgst_per,DoubleType,true), StructField(created_at,TimestampType,true), StructField(description,StringType,true), StructField(discount,DoubleType,true), StructField(discount_amount,IntegerType,true), StructField(discount_per,DoubleType,true), StructField(doctor,StructType(StructField($db,StringType,true), StructField($id,StructType(StructField(oid,StringType,true)),true), StructField($ref,StringType,true)),true), StructField(doctor_fee,DoubleType,true), StructField(etl_billType,StringType,true), StructField(etl_billedOutlet,StringType,true), StructField(etl_data,BooleanType,true), StructField(etl_data_batch,StringType,true), StructField(etl_doctor,StringType,true), StructField(etl_item,StringType,true), StructField(etl_surgery,StringType,true), StructField(etl_taxMaster,StringType,true), StructField(igst_amount,DoubleType,true), StructField(igst_per,DoubleType,true), StructField(initial_amount,DoubleType,true), StructField(inventoryItemBatchDetail,StructType(StructField($db,StringType,true), StructField($id,StructType(StructField(oid,StringType,true)),true), StructField($ref,StringType,true)),true), StructField(inventoryLocationStock,StructType(StructField($ref,StringType,true), StructField($id,StructType(StructField(oid,StringType,true)),true), StructField($db,StringType,true)),true), StructField(inventoryStockLocation,StructType(StructField($ref,StringType,true), StructField($id,StructType(StructField(oid,StringType,true)),true), StructField($db,StringType,true)),true), StructField(ipAppointment,StructType(StructField($ref,StringType,true), StructField($id,StructType(StructField(oid,StringType,true)),true), StructField($db,StringType,true)),true), StructField(is_deleted,BooleanType,true), StructField(is_despatched_item,BooleanType,true), StructField(is_modified,BooleanType,true), StructField(is_modified_deleted,BooleanType,true), StructField(is_old_bill,BooleanType,true), StructField(is_previous_bill_item,BooleanType,true), StructField(is_sponsor_bill,BooleanType,true), StructField(is_stent_invoice_loaded,BooleanType,true), StructField(is_tax_reversed,BooleanType,true), StructField(item,StructType(StructField($db,StringType,true), StructField($id,StructType(StructField(oid,StringType,true)),true), StructField($ref,StringType,true)),true), StructField(item_category,StructType(StructField($db,StringType,true), StructField($id,StructType(StructField(oid,StringType,true)),true), StructField($ref,StringType,true)),true), StructField(item_group,StructType(StructField($ref,StringType,true), StructField($id,StructType(StructField(oid,StringType,true)),true), StructField($db,StringType,true)),true), StructField(item_movement_summary,StructType(StructField($ref,StringType,true), StructField($id,StructType(StructField(oid,StringType,true)),true), StructField($db,StringType,true)),true), StructField(legacy_billno,StringType,true), StructField(legacy_branchcode,StringType,true), StructField(legacy_concessionrate,StringType,true), StructField(legacy_dailycharge,StringType,true), StructField(legacy_dosage,StringType,true), StructField(legacy_emergency,StringType,true), StructField(legacy_itemcessamount,StringType,true), StructField(legacy_medicineusagereference,StringType,true), StructField(legacy_oldbillitemcost,StringType,true), StructField(legacy_oldvatamount,StringType,true), StructField(legacy_oldvatpercentage,StringType,true), StructField(legacy_prescriptionreference,StringType,true), StructField(legacy_productserialnumber,StringType,true), StructField(legacy_recordlocked,StringType,true), StructField(legacy_salestaxpercentage,StringType,true), StructField(legacy_sellingcgstamount,StringType,true), StructField(legacy_sellingdiscountamount,DoubleType,true), StructField(legacy_sellingdiscountpercentage,DoubleType,true), StructField(legacy_sellingsgstamount,StringType,true), StructField(legacy_slno,StringType,true), StructField(legacy_transfered,StringType,true), StructField(legacy_updategstvat,StringType,true), StructField(legacy_vatamount,StringType,true), StructField(legacy_vatinclusive,StringType,true), StructField(legacy_vatpercentage,StringType,true), StructField(less,BooleanType,true), StructField(local_storage_delete,BooleanType,true), StructField(master_tax,StructType(StructField($db,StringType,true), StructField($id,StructType(StructField(oid,StringType,true)),true), StructField($ref,StringType,true)),true), StructField(modified_at,TimestampType,true), StructField(mrp_price,DoubleType,true), StructField(organization,StructType(StructField($ref,StringType,true), StructField($id,StructType(StructField(oid,StringType,true)),true), StructField($db,StringType,true)),true), StructField(organization_code,StringType,true), StructField(package_order,IntegerType,true), StructField(previous_return_qty,StringType,true), StructField(quantity,IntegerType,true), StructField(rack,StructType(StructField($ref,StringType,true), StructField($id,StructType(StructField(oid,StringType,true)),true), StructField($db,StringType,true)),true), StructField(reversed_gst_amount,DoubleType,true), StructField(sess_amount,DoubleType,true), StructField(sgst_amount,DoubleType,true), StructField(sgst_per,DoubleType,true), StructField(surgery,StructType(StructField($ref,StringType,true), StructField($id,StructType(StructField(oid,StringType,true)),true)),true), StructField(taxMaster,NullType,true), StructField(total,DoubleType,true), StructField(total_sales_return_amount,DoubleType,true), StructField(unit_price,DoubleType,true)))) [bill_doctor#3582,is_previous_bill_item#3616,total#3666,item#3620,bills#3586,doctor#3594,_id#3577,quantity#3658,bill_date#3581,discount#3591,amount#3578] PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(is_previous_bill_item), EqualTo(is_previous_bill_item,false)], ReadSchema: struct<bill_doctor:struct<$ref:string,$id:struct<oid:string>,$db:string>,is_previous_bill_item:bo...
      :           :           :           :           :           +- *(49) Sort [bills_id#6120 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      :           :           :           :           :              +- Exchange hashpartitioning(bills_id#6120, 200)
```

Comment: Can you give the complete traceback of the error? What is the spark version? What is the MongoDB version? Is there authentication set up on the DB?

Comment: MongoDB Version: 4.2.0,Pyspark version: 2.4.4, when running locally the DB has authentication but when running on server, DB has authentication and also I have specified authSource and all for running in server

Comment: Do you have any UDF's in your code?

Comment: No, I dont have any UDF's in my code